# Sending a message through a particular client port in remoting

Tags: c#, remoting

I am doing applications in .net remoting.actually we register a channel in the server side and connect the client using the iP and port of the server,but i want to send my messages from client through a specific port for ex: 8085 or 8086.how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why? There are numerous disadvantages to specifying the client port:

- the client must effectively be single-threaded
- TCP will impose a two-minute TIME_WAIT before you can reuse the port.

Firewall administrators sometimes like to create these rules not realizing that they cripple the client. Such rules don't actually server any useful purpose that I'm aware of.

Comment: if possible please tell mehow to achieve this

Comment: will u tell me how to do that?

Comment: I asked you why? You need to answer that. I strongly doubt that this is what you should be doing.

Comment: my network administarators blocked all the ports and i am supposed to
use the only port they give? thats the reason ok

Comment: If the network administrators are trying to administer outbound ports they need re-education. Controlling outbound port numbers adds nothing by way of security; it cripples client applications by only letting them use a single connection at a time and enforcing a two-minute delay between closing a connection and opening the next one; and in the cases sometimes seen where they allow a range of outbound ports there is no TCP API that will support that, so they are creating programming difficulties or impossibilities.

Show them this thread and ask them to justify their policy.